# RaspberryPI and MAME ROMS

Tags: raspbian

I have my PI for over a year now, and never got the time to work on it. It used to boot up months ago, but now it does not anymore.

I would like to make myPI in Arcade machine with help of MAME, maybe even later do some carpenter work on case.

I have been looking tutorials and always failed to understand what is it that I need to do.

Is there a download with MAME already preinstalled for SSD where I can only add ROMS and bring the childhood memories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a premade distro for this use called RetroPie

[Here's a link to that](http://blog.petrockblock.com/download/retropie-project-image/)

That sites the hub for that project as well, I'm yet to get any response from a forum post there although there seems to be some good info.

Although It's preconfigured It can still be a lot of hassle, and documentation is pretty slim from what I've seen so far. It's technically in Beta apparently, though I wouldn't expect that to ever change.

Remember that the Mame roms need to be left in Zip form when you transfer them over to the Pie.

Comment: No worries - I'm just reinstalling here, make sure you back up! :) theres some good info here http://elinux.org/RPi_Beginners and here http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2014/06/playing-old-skool-games-on-a-raspberry-pi/ and here's the official wiki https://github.com/petrockblog/RetroPie-Setup/wiki hope it goes well!